# the exact meaning of "as many as"

Tags: phrase-meaning

*According to government data released last month, the country may have **as many as** 110,000 pathological gamblers that account for 1.2 percent of the total population, or nearly the average number of gamblers per capita in other European Union countries.*

Source: http://www.aljazeera.com/indepth/features/2016/08/czech-republic-dangerous-gambling-addiction-160829110812215.html

I would like to ask what "as many as" means in the context. Is it possible to change it into "at least". So the mentioned number of gamblers is probably larger.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[No, **as many as** actually means "at most".](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/as+many+as)  There could be *as many pathological gamblers as 110,000,* but not more.  In other words, it sets a maximum number, not a minimum.

Comment: In another context "as many as" can mean the number (of people/widgets) required, however large; as in: Hire as many people as you need to complete the job. http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/as+many+as